# mapping of an array using array.map() is failing

Tags: reactjs, arraylist, javascript-objects

I am using array.map() to list down items, from an array of objects, but it is giving undefined as a result.
Have i done any error in my code below?

```
const Reminder = {
      Tag: Tag || null,
      Starter: KickStart,
      SendTime: TimeInput || null,
      TimeUnits: Units || null,
      ExecValue: Exec || null,
      Message: TextInput,
    };

const [Reminders, setReminders] = useState([]);

 const HandleSave = () => {
      let AddReminder = Reminders.concat(Reminder);
      setReminders(AddReminder)};

const myReminder = Reminders.map(reminder => {
    <p>{reminder.Starter}</p>
  })

<div>
                {Reminders.length == 0 ? (
                  <p>
                    You have not saved any Reminder templates. Click the Add
                    button to start
                  </p>
                ) : (
                  <div>
                    {myReminder}
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
```

a console.log for the Reminders array, after the using inputs data is below:

```
[{…}]
0: {Tag: 'tag-2', Starter: 'before', SendTime: '1', TimeUnits: 'hours', ExecValue: null, …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

however, the console log for the myReminder is below:

```
0: undefined
length: 1
```

I cant locate my error

Comment: Might be a typo but your array is "Reminder" without an "s" and you are mapping "Reminders" with an "s"

Comment: @Matt, I have edited the code, while posting, I forgot to include the "Reminders" array

Comment: What does set `setReminders` do?

Comment: Each time a user enters data, the Reminders array is updated with the setReminders

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the map function.

```js
const myReminder = Reminders.map(reminder => {
    return <p>{reminder.Starter}</p>
 })
```

Just put `return` before the `<p>` tag.

Comment: Oh God!, Am even embarrased, thanks @Kumar